# Javascript Foreach loop over multiple selector elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

Im struggling to create a basic Javascript foreach loop.
my selecter matches multiple elements
i want to execute the addition of `&ws=true` to all elements matching my selector.
This is my code, which works for one element, but not multiple

```
(
  function()
   {
   var selector = "form[class='cart']"
   document.querySelector (selector).action += "&ws=true"
   }
)
();
```

Comment: does this mean that you have several forms on the same page? there is seldom an interest to make this

Comment: Hi mister Jojo. Yes there are multiple on the same page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector` to get **all** matching elements instead of just the first matching element.
- You selector can be simplified to `form.cart`. Only use `form[class="cart"]` if you want to exclude `<form>` elements with other additional class names applied to them.
- You can use a `for-of` loop directly with a `NodeListOf<T>`.
- Because the `for` subject (`const form`) is scoped to the loop's body there's no need for an IIFE wrapper (i.e. there's no scope pollution).

Like so:

```
for( const form of document.querySelectorAll( 'form.cart' ) ) {
    form.action += "&ws=true";
}
```

---

#### Alternatively, without using ECMAScript 6 language features:

If you can't use modern JavaScript (`const`, `for-of`, etc) then use this:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll( 'form.cart' );
for( var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++ ) {
    elements[i].action += "&ws=true";
}
```

Comment: Hi Dai, thanks for answering.
I am using this javascript inside Google Tagmanager, and it appears that tagmanager is unable to proces this language. However this is all new to me.

this is the error i get:

This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better: for-of loop.